# When did Jewish court systems replace Yisro's "chiefs" system?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, history, beit-din-court, parashas-yisro, parashas-shoftim

The Jews in the desert implemented Yisro's "chiefs" system to act as judges, but we know at some point the nation transitioned to the courts system with judges of 3, 23, 71, etc.  At what point and why did this transition occur?  Or were the two systems operated in parallel and related to each other?  If so, what was their relationship, and what happened to the "chiefs" aspect of the system, which seems to have been dropped at some point?

Similar question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98592/whatever-happened-to-the-chiefs-of-the-10-50-100-and-1-000/98595#98595), but I don't think it answers my questions.  Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Was Moshe adjudicating disputes or was he also handling one party questions?

Comment: @ClintEastwood seems adjudicating disputes was at least part of the equation - Exodus 18:16 - "I judge between a man and his neighbor, and I make known the statutes of God and His teachings."

Comment: The one party system still goes on and single rabbis can arbitrate disputes outside of a formal beit din setting. A follow up question is did Moshe singlehandedly deal with capital cases? In the cases of the blasphemer and the stick gathering man, he asked God what to do. I would say Moshe's system was never replaced but the court system dealt with different matters.